# Am i using correct relationships in this UML class diagram? Should i keep android implementation in mind while making class diagram?

Tags: android, uml

I am working on a tourism android application as a final year project. But i am very confused in making the class diagram. I am not understanding should i keep android implementation in mind while creating the class diagram. I have made this so far

[image: UML Class Diagram]

Comment: Which relationships are you concerned about? And what do you mean by "keep android implementation in mind"?

Comment: For example _Register_ class has an object of _User_ class as an attribute so i represented it as a composition relationship. "keep android implementation in mind" i mean in android we have activity classes so in this class diagram should we also make them? @qwerty_so

Comment: Got the first part. But activity classes does not ring a bell. What are they supposed to do?

Comment: For example _Register, Login, Events ..._ classes will be implemented as an _activity class_ in android. So should i inherit them from android classes such as AppCompactActivity in the class diagram ? @qwerty_so

Comment: Yes. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: And one more thing: please edit your question so your comments are reflected as part of the question!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the relationships:

- Your `Register` has a local attribute typed `User` *and* you have a composite aggregation to `User`. It's better to used role names in such cases instead of the attributes. Just put `-user` near the diamond and remove the local attribute.
- The `has a` labels are superfluous. You use them with ERD, but in UML you don't need it. The relation between associated classes is expressed via role names much better.
- Keep class names singular (`Place` without 's', etc.).

Just to make you aware of this: when `User` composes `Register` it means that when you remove `User` it is responsible to also remove the composite `Register`. Looks like it should be the other way round. However, I just would remove the diamond and make it a simple association. The register just holds `User` references. Best to put according multiplicity towards `User` (that'd be `0..*` most likely).

Regarding the "activity classes": As I understood your classes (like `Register`) inherit from some system class (I'd guess it's called `Activity`). That would be you draw a generalization from your class to that `Activity`. In order to not crowd your diagram you will omit that from the diagram. Remember: one diagram is one view on your diagram. You can and will have more than one view. So create another class diagram that just shows the generalization(s) without any other relation. Together these diagrams will represent a combined view of your design.